# swift is it possible to change (configure) the background of button for many states on the interface builder

Tags: ios, swift

I change the text color for each button using code like this:

```
thirdTimeOption.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Constants.centuryGothic.rawValue, size: CGFloat(13))
thirdTimeOption.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 166.0/255.0, green: 142.0/255.0, blue: 83.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
thirdTimeOption.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
```

It is good, it is working good, however, now I want also to change the background for each button if it is selected or not selected. I didn't find any function to set and configure the background color according to a state, the same think I find for the button color.

I was reading online and they say that I can do that on interface builder, but i dont know, I search but can't find

#### the users suggestion to do this:

if sender.selected{

```
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 166.0/255.0, green: 142.0/255.0, blue: 83.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}else {
    sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

but look what i got when i added that:
[image]

however, what i want is just changing that blue color to my color

Comment: The "background" is the background _image_. And there _is_ a function for setting the background image to depend on the state. So why not use that?

Comment: @matt i dont want to but a background as image, i need the color just the color, in order to keep the rounded button, i know i can round also by code, but i am trying to ask if i can change the color of the background not as image.

Comment: The background image can easily consist of a solid color. This has nothing to do with the roundedness of the button. You have not shown what else you are doing with the button (your code shows only some title color stuff) so it's hard to help you. If you want help, be more open.

Comment: yes, that can be done..by making an image filled with a color. but @matt the author is also asking that it should be done in Interface builder.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari Well, that's just too bad. I'm concentrating on what _can_ be done. That is more productive than banging one's head against what _can't_ be done.

Comment: @matt i added my result for what the people suggestion

Comment: @sarah I edited my answer. Check that out. Also make your UIButton as Custom type. You will not get that what you posted in the pic

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari i definately dn't want a  custom type

Comment: @sarah Just give a try to the code I posted.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari it is not about trying, i really don't want that solution, i believe this is a simple issue, and it just have another simpler sllution. maybe your code works really thank you, but i will wait for other people to give me a simpler solution

Comment: @sarah just FYI.. my code works fine with System Button type too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution myself

```
 @IBAction func selectTimeOption(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.selected = !sender.selected
        if sender.selected{
            sender.tintColor = UIColor(red: 166.0/255.0, green: 142.0/255.0, blue: 83.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }else {
            sender.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well I got one solution for you. Make a extension of UIImage class and write this code.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
extension UIImage{
    static func imageFromColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1);

    // create a 1 by 1 pixel context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0);
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect);

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;

  }
}
```

Now you can use this in your ViewController class.

```
let normalImageColor = UIImage.imageFromColor(UIColor.redColor())
let selectedImageColor = UIImage.imageFromColor(UIColor.greenColor())

//Use this with buttons
myButton.setBackgroundImage(normalImageColor, forState: .Normal)
myButton.setBackgroundImage(selectedImageColor, forState: .Selected)
```

and you are done.

**Alternative Ways**

```
if(button.selected){
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
else{
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
}
```

For Highlighted state you can use

```
if(button.highlighted){
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
}
```

Check in IBAction

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    if(sender.selected){
        //Change colors
    }
}
```

Comment: i know i can do that but that i have to do whenever the button click, but i am asking different think, i need to say that just one time, the same think i do with the color of the text.

Comment: For background colors you can do in the `IBAction` of the button, where you can assign the color with checking whether sender is selected or highlighted.  I couldn't get you what you want to do?

Comment: yes i can do that on the ibaction, but is there any way to set that just once? (like the color of the text) i set that just once in the view did load. but what you see, the code will be executed everytime the ibaction work

Comment: if you tell me there is no other way, i do that in the ibaction. i am just asking to know the possible solutions

Comment: No, as far as I know, for background colors we can't do that.

Comment: we can do for background images from Interface builder

Comment: i foudn the soution mysef. i write an ansewr, i will +1 your answer because you help me but sorry i can't accept your answer

Comment: @sarah You asked about background colors and not tints

Comment: i didn't know that there is something call tints, i study online now and i found it, and i show u the picture already,

Comment: @sarah Also I would like to remind you that you asked for a solution without `IBActions` code and you asked that to be set just once in code. The answer you posted neither meets any.